# Change SharePoint FormField ItemId on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

On my page I have SharePoint people editor and formfield:

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor runat="server" ID="frmUser" AutoPostBack="true" />
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ID="frmPermissions"/>
```

When the PeopleEditor value is changed the formfield should display the new list item:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        if (!Page.IsPostBack || string.IsNullOrEmpty(frmUser.CommaSeparatedAccounts))
        {
            frmUser.CommaSeparatedAccounts = UsersListHelper.CurrentUser.LoginName;
        }

        UsersListHelper.GetSelectedUser(frmUser.CommaSeparatedAccounts);

        frmPermissions.ItemId = UsersListHelper.SelectedUser.Item.ID;
        frmPermissions.ListId = UsersListHelper.List.ID;
        frmPermissions.FieldName = UsersListHelper._permissionsFieldName;

        frmPermissions.ControlMode = Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControlMode.Edit;
    }
```

But I can't get it to work :(. First load goes okay, but postbacks are not. When I enter new user and submit, the formfield does not show at all, and if I submit once more - then it shows the proper item. I would appreciate any tip you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move

```
base.OnLoad(e);
```

at the end of `protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)` method body.
Or move your code into OnInit method (or some other earlier method of page life cycle)

Comment: Well, I need that viewstate from another control, so I cannot use OnInit. I'm now thinking about avoiding postback somehow. Thanks for the tip anyway.